# Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Could not flush and close the file system output stream to hdfs

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, checkpoint

**AsynchronousException{java.lang.Exception: Could not materialize checkpoint 32726 for operator Source:**

**Hadoop:hadoop-2.8.5

Flink:flink-1.7.2-bin-hadoop28-scala_2.11**

The Hadoop Cluster is normal and healthy.

```bash
$ hdfs dfsadmin -safemode get
Safe mode is OFF

$ hdfs dfsadmin -report
Configured Capacity: 54716792832 (50.96 GB)
Present Capacity: 37640894006 (35.06 GB)
DFS Remaining: 37224263680 (34.67 GB)
DFS Used: 416630326 (397.33 MB)
DFS Used%: 1.11%
Under replicated blocks: 12
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0
Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 0
Pending deletion blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Live datanodes (3):

Name: 192.168.13.73:50010 (slave1)
Hostname: slave1
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 18238930944 (16.99 GB)
DFS Used: 138713073 (132.29 MB)
Non DFS Used: 4678150159 (4.36 GB)
DFS Remaining: 13422067712 (12.50 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.76%
DFS Remaining%: 73.59%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Tue May 07 10:21:54 CST 2019


Name: 192.168.13.74:50010 (slave2)
Hostname: slave2
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 18238930944 (16.99 GB)
DFS Used: 139204370 (132.76 MB)
Non DFS Used: 7022983406 (6.54 GB)
DFS Remaining: 11076743168 (10.32 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.76%
DFS Remaining%: 60.73%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Tue May 07 10:21:52 CST 2019


Name: 192.168.13.75:50010 (slave3)
Hostname: slave3
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 18238930944 (16.99 GB)
DFS Used: 138712883 (132.29 MB)
Non DFS Used: 5374765261 (5.01 GB)
DFS Remaining: 12725452800 (11.85 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.76%
DFS Remaining%: 69.77%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
Xceivers: 1
Last contact: Tue May 07 10:21:52 CST 2019
```

**env.setStateBackend((StateBackend) new FsStateBackend(hdfs_path));

After about 2 days of normal running with Flink Streaming Job.

FlinkSQL(rowtime): HOP Window(5 minutes, 1 minutes)

After the job is restarted, the data is partially lost.**

Exception Details:

```bash
AsynchronousException{java.lang.Exception: Could not materialize checkpoint 32726 for operator Source: Custom Source -> Filter -> Map -> Timestamps/Watermarks -> from: (...) -> time attribute: (rowtime) (1/3).}
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointExceptionHandler.tryHandleCheckpointException(StreamTask.java:1153)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.handleExecutionException(StreamTask.java:947)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.run(StreamTask.java:884)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Could not materialize checkpoint 32726 for operator Source: Custom Source -> Filter -> Map -> Timestamps/Watermarks -> from: (...) -> time attribute: (rowtime) (1/3).
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.handleExecutionException(StreamTask.java:942)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Could not flush and close the file system output stream to hdfs://master:9000/flink/checkpoints/PaycoreContextHopJob/0d71451e3fa1368e500175f9138d1e65/chk-32726/41598f08-35e4-4b9d-81c7-901a0c661fb2 in order to obtain the stream state handle
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FutureUtil.runIfNotDoneAndGet(FutureUtil.java:53)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.OperatorSnapshotFinalizer.<init>(OperatorSnapshotFinalizer.java:53)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask$AsyncCheckpointRunnable.run(StreamTask.java:853)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not flush and close the file system output stream to hdfs://master:9000/flink/checkpoints/PaycoreContextHopJob/0d71451e3fa1368e500175f9138d1e65/chk-32726/41598f08-35e4-4b9d-81c7-901a0c661fb2 in order to obtain the stream state handle
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FsCheckpointStreamFactory$FsCheckpointStateOutputStream.closeAndGetHandle(FsCheckpointStreamFactory.java:326)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackend$DefaultOperatorStateBackendSnapshotStrategy$1.callInternal(DefaultOperatorStateBackend.java:767)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.DefaultOperatorStateBackend$DefaultOperatorStateBackendSnapshotStrategy$1.callInternal(DefaultOperatorStateBackend.java:696)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.state.AsyncSnapshotCallable.call(AsyncSnapshotCallable.java:76)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.flink.util.FutureUtil.runIfNotDoneAndGet(FutureUtil.java:50)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /flink/checkpoints/PaycoreContextHopJob/0d71451e3fa1368e500175f9138d1e65/chk-32726/41598f08-35e4-4b9d-81c7-901a0c661fb2 could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 3 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1726)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2567)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:829)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:447)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:793)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2489)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1345)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:444)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:409)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:346)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1838)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1638)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:704)
```

Comment: Was it just a single checkpoint? Or does every checkpoint fails?

Comment: A single checkpoint. After the job restarted, it can run for a few hours.The most important thing is another job, which is the Tumble window. It has been running normally for 2d10h without checkpoint exception.

Comment: Recently, I have running 4 jobs, but 2 jobs of them failed by hdfs checkpoint.